# How do I code jQuery to reference an image in my root folder for a background image?

Tags: jquery, background, directory, root

I want to enable users to change the background on my webpage. Here's some of my jQuery code:

```
$("#green_box1").click(function() {
        $.backstretch('http://www.cosmetichouseintl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/MP900406576.jpg');
        })
```

I am using the backstretch plug-in featured here: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

It works perfectly, except, as far as I can tell, I can only reference images from a web address, and I would prefer to reference a background image from my root folder. Is there a way I can code differently to reference an image from my root folder rather than an image that's online?

Comment: you can give image path relative to the html page where this javascript is embedded

Comment: [here's a fun read about relative and absolute paths](http://www.uvsc.edu/disted/decourses/dgm/2120/IN/steinja/lessons/06/06_04.html)

Comment: "Is there a way I can code differently to reference an image from my root folder rather than an image that's online?" Well, it has to be online somewhere for other people to see it. Or do you distribute static html in a zip file?

Comment: Forgive me, could you be more specific? I am new to this.

Comment: I don't intend for this site to go live; It's a project for a college class in which I hand over the root folder.

Comment: you can give relative path to the root directory .if your image is in images folder give the path as images/image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If image.jpg is in the same folder as the file your code is in, you can simply use:

```
$("#green_box1").click(function() {
    $.backstretch('image.jpg');
})
```

If when you are in the folder of your file, the image.jpg is inside a folder called "yourFolder", you can use:

```
$("#green_box1").click(function() {
    $.backstretch('yourFolder/image.jpg');
})
```

Comment: This worked! Fantastic! Once again, I feel silly for asking; I didn't think it would be as simple as that. I thought I had tried something similar, but I guess I didn't have it entered quite right before. Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

currently, you are providing

http://www.cosmetichouseintl.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/MP900406576.jpg

which means MP900406576.jpg is present on the cosmetichouseint1 domain and 
present in the directory structure as wp-content/uploads/2011/05/

Similarly you can too put path to ur image file like

```
$("#green_box1").click(function() {
    $.backstretch('path_to_the_imag_folder/imagename.jpg');
})
```